# Privacy lists in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I would like to block all incoming presence updates from my roster. I have tried using privacy lists by sending the following IQ.

```
<iq id='oQQwF-18' type='set'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
    <list name="subscription">
      <item action="deny" order="9" type="subscription" value="to">
        <presence-in/>
      </item>
    </list>
  </query>
</iq>
```

I can see that the privacy list is being store in MySQL but i still receive presence updates from roster buddies.

I am aware of `mod_client_state`, but i would like to give privacy lists a try first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XEP-0016, when matching for subscription types, you need to match each subscription type separately.  With the stanza above, you are blocking incoming presence stanzas from users whose subscription status is "to", but presumably most of them have subscription status "both" (and some might have "from").  Try this:

```xml
<iq id='oQQwF-18' type='set'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
    <list name="subscription">
      <item action="deny" order="9" type="subscription" value="to">
        <presence-in/>
      </item>
      <item action="deny" order="10" type="subscription" value="from">
        <presence-in/>
      </item>
      <item action="deny" order="11" type="subscription" value="both">
        <presence-in/>
      </item>
    </list>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Besides, you may need to set the `subscription` list to be the active privacy list:

```xml
<iq type='set' id='active1'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
  <active name='subscription'/>
</query>
</iq>
```

Comment: Setting the privacy list as Active does the trick. I have noticed that we need to make it the list active every time a new session is started. Is there any way of persisting this ?

Comment: Also, since i have blocked incoming presence stanzas, is there a way for me to query a particular users presence(considering the fact that the users are subscribed to each others presence) ?